# Type check a WebControl

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know in VBA how to do a Select..Case comparison for a controls Type, as such:

```
Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
  case is = "ListBox"
    ...
  case is = "ComboBox"
    ...
  ...
End Select
```

In VB.Net, can i use the general value, as above, or will i have to have a Namespace qualifier in the text?

Currently implementation:

```
public function Validate(byref ctrl as WebControl) as boolean
  select case TypeName(ctrl)
    case is = "TextBox"
      ....
    case is = "Label"
      ....
    ...
  End select
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the "name" of the type, you can use the type directly:

```
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf c Is TextBox
            ' its a Textbox
        Case TypeOf c Is Label
            ' its a label
        Case Else
            'foo
    End Select
```

Comment: wish i could use this logic in VBA...tyvm works perfect....and thanks for providing me with a different view on this type of validation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you expecting somthing like this
You can use [TypeOf Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
Dim ctrl As Control
        For Each ctrl Me.Controls
            If (TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox) Then
                ''do something
            End If
            If (TypeOf ctrl Is Label) Then
                ''do something
            End If
        Next ctrl
```

**Update**

Using `case`

```
  select case True
    case  TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox
      ....
    case TypeOf ctrl Is Label
      ....
    ...
  End select
```

Comment: trying to stay away from the If...Then...ElseIf... nightmare for this logic.  But thanx for the alternative

Comment: @GoldBishop: I just put as an example. Basicaly you just need `TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox` only!!!

Comment: I know, and about 5 years ago, would have been my approach, of coarse i was a novice designer.

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: Your code will not compile. ctrl is WebControl. `TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox` is boolean. So you would need to compare `type` against `boolean`. So the error you would get is `Operator "=" is not defined for Types ...`

Comment: @igrimpe: of course, it shoud be `true` instead of `ctrl`. Thanks